# What is the correct way to use grids?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I have just started to learn bootstrap. And this is the first time I have ever used grids for a layout. Something I don't understand about grids is where I should put my content.

Should I do like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <p> My content </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or should I use a parent element for my content like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div> or <footer> or <aside> or <content> etc
            <p> My content </p>
        </div> or </footer> or </aside> or </content> etc
    </div>
</div>
```

If the answer is the second. Is there ever a reason where it is okay to put content directly into the column? Or have I misunderstod everything and it should be done in a completly other way?

What is "best practice"?

Comment: Bootstrap grid system designed to provide you tools for creating a page layout. You can put inside what you need: plain text, or html elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is like this:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
       <div class="your-widget-name">
         Widget code here…
       <div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This way, your widgets can be used across multiple layouts.
Using separate divs for the grid can increase the amount of markup, but make the code easier to maintain.

Comment: Okay, so I dont need to use any other element as a "container"? What about "screen readers" how does a grid system affect them, if for example <footer> is placed inside a "col-md-12" div? Do I HAVE TO use the bootstrap columns ex. "col-md-12" on div's? Or could I for example use <content class="col-md-12"> instead? What is best practise if would need a "<content>". Should I use the content tag with a coulmn class. Or chould the content tag have a div parent with column class?

Comment: You probably will need a 'container' class. You don't have to use the 'col-...' classes on DIVs, but really, I  think it is easier. Probably you need to try it for yourself and see. :)

Answer (score 0):

Content should be put inside your column as stated in bootstrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro)

Both are correct in your example since grid is just for layout, you can put any block or inline elements in it.

Comment: Okay, so I dont need to use any other element as a "container"? What about "screen readers" how does a grid system affect them, if for example <footer> is placed inside a "col-md-12" div? Do I HAVE TO use the bootstrap columns ex. "col-md-12" on div's? Or could I for example use <content class="col-md-12"> instead? What is best practise if would need a "<content>". Should I use the content tag with a coulmn class. Or chould the content tag have a div parent with column class?

Answer (score 0):

Most important rule to follow - `.container` is parent,its child's are `.row`, `.col` goes inside rows and your content goes in `.col`.

Eg. You want to put Image on center with paragraphs on side.

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="image"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <p>Lorem ipsum summun</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```